# Forces are confusing?

Tags: forces, gravity, newtonian-gravity

Why is gravitational force only a pull force ? And why does any force even exist between two uncharged particles . Shouldn't the positive negative attraction be nullified by the positive - positive and negative - negative repulsion ?

Comment: What do you mean by positive-negative attraction being nullified by positive positive and negative negative attraction? Like charges do not attract, they repel.

Comment: Sorry ! Hope now it is clear

Answer (score 0):

Gravitational force remains a pull force as long as negative mass is not discovered.

Force existing between two uncharged particles is not electromagnetic force, but gravitational force, which depends not on the charge but on the mass.

Comment: But tension force exists because of electromagnetic forces. How does that happen ? . Why doesn't the charges nullify attraction and repulsion ? And how does tension remains a pull force only ?

Comment: That's something you've got to think for yourself.

Comment: OK thanks ! I will think over it and then when I am done I will be glad to inform you about it